# JavaScript which inside JSP doesn't work when I used java tag

Tags: java, javascript, json, jsp

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    var ilceler = "${ilceler}";
});
```

It doesn't print "Ready!" to console. When I debug with chrome, I saw

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    var subChildList = "";
    ilceler = JSON.parse(" [
{"id":"xx","tag":"xx","name":"xxx","fatherid":"66","fathertag":"il"},
{"id":"xx","tag":"xx","name":"xxx","fatherid":"66","fathertag":"il"},
{"id":"xx","tag":"xx","name":"xxxxx","fatherid":"66","fathertag":"il"},
{"id":"xx","tag":"xx","name":"xxxx","fatherid":"66","fathertag":"il"},
{"id":"x","tag":"xx","name":"xxx xxx","fatherid":"66","fathertag":"il"},
{"id":"xx","tag":"xx","name":"xxxx","fatherid":"66","fathertag":"il"},
{"id":"xx","tag":"xx","name":"xxx","fatherid":"66","fathertag":"il"},
{"id":"xx","tag":"xx","name":"xxxx","fatherid":"66","fathertag":"il"},
{"id":"xx","tag":"xx","name":"xxx","fatherid":"66","fathertag":"il"},
{"id":"xx","tag":"xx","name":"xx\/xxx","fatherid":"66","fathertag":"il"},
{"id":"xx","tag":"xx","name":"xxx","fatherid":"66","fathertag":"il"},
{"id":"xx","tag":"xx","name":"xxx","fatherid":"66","fathertag":"il"},
{"id":"xx","tag":"xx","name":"xxx","fatherid":"66","fathertag":"il"},
{"id":"xx","tag":"xx","name":"xxxx","fatherid":"66","fathertag":"il"}]");
});
```

My data is true, but why this function doesn't work. 
Note: My data includes UTF-8 characters.
Note2: I can work with string instead of json.

```
var a = ${tag}
console.log(a) >> "It's my tag"
```

Comment: Can you also post the JSP/Java tag?

Comment: ${ilceler} it's my JSP/Java tag.

Comment: what is `var ilceler = "${ilceler}";` supposed to mean?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the newlines? Since you say you use a JSON string rather than a JSON object, remember that javascript doesn't recognize multi-line strings.

Comment: I add ilceler to model at server-side as
map.addAttribute("ilceler", "JSONOBJECT AS STRING");

Comment: I can reach same object using ajax. So my json object is ok, but I cannot reach using JSP/Java tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seems to me that you need to remove the quotes surrounding your variable.

So it should be

```
var ilceler = ${ilceler};
```

The JSP/JSTL interpreter will leave these quotes and hence your object will be regarded as a String value instead of a JSON object. Also if your second output is the output in the browser you can see it's not valid JSON.